# Is a server with a public Ip reachable on a subnet with nat?

Tags: routing, ip, nat, subnet, amazon-vpc

This is inside an amazon vpc, I have a non-public subnet associated with a routing table that routes all `0.0.0.0/0` traffic over to a `nat`( there is also one vpn connection )

```
Destination   Target  Status Propagated
10.100.0.0/16 local   Active No
0.0.0.0/0     nat     Active No
10.20.0.0/24  vgw     Active No
```

The nat has a `elastic ip of 52.71.71.71`.

Now there is an instance in this subnet that was assigned a public ip.

```
Instance private ip: 10.100.100.100 
Instance public  ip: 52.30.30.30
```

It's a web server with a security group that allows all traffic.

I get the splash page when I navigate to `http://10.100.100.100` because I have the VPN connection and can reach the private ip without getting routed throught the nat.

I get nothing when I navigate to `http://52.30.30.30`;

My question is, When I navigate to the `http://52.30.30.30`, does my request still reach the instance, I just do not receive a response?

If I understand routing tables correctly, they only direct outgoing traffic, So I'm thinking I hit the server on it's public IP, but the reply gets lost because it is directed throu the NAT that changes the ip to `52.71.71.71`.

If I do not hit the server, I am lost as to what mechanism prevents me from reaching my instance on it's public IP.

Comment: Question is not that clear, Can you paste the routing table also, and elaborate using that? **Secondly**, NAT works both ways it is a stateful thing. So if a packet has gone out from a source and NATed from it, It will remember the connection and change back the IP when reply is received.

Comment: What I am suspecting is: You are trying to reach the web server using an IP(are you?) **52.30.30.30** which is the Public IP of that instance, Whereas it may be available on its hostname only. As most probably the web server doesn't know what is 52.30.30.30 but it probably knows what is **xyz.com**. (Virtualhost directive), Try doing  a TCPDump you may find something.